# Master theorem for $T(n)=T(n-1)+O(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

The recurrence of selection sort is $$T(n) = T(n-1)+ O(n).$$ Can we apply the master theorem to this recurrence? I am confused because the master theorem can be applied to the following recurrence

$$T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n),$$

where $a \ge 1$ and $b > 1$. But for selection sort, $b=1$. I am trying to apply the master theorem and stuck.

Comment: Are you sure this question isn't already answered on this site? Please try to have a look

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running time of selection sort](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54562/running-time-of-selection-sort)

Comment: Nope. It is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Simple; the Master Theorem doesn't apply to this problem.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. What would $a$ and $b$ be? In this case, solve the recurrence directly (using the real cost function, not that O(n) bound).

Comment: @Discretelizard I don't think this is a duplicate. The question isn't about selection sort; it's about how to use the master theorem to solve a particular recurrence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The master theorem isn't the appropriate theorem for *every* recurrence. As an example, your recurrence isn't of the type tackled by the master theorem, though it is easy to solve directly using the well-known identity
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \Theta(n^2). $$
You should think of the master theorem as a tool, not a liability. It is supposed to help you – use it if you need it, but feel free to use any other approach as you see fit. The only cases you absolutely *have* to apply the master theorem is when answering questions on a homework or a test that say you must use it; in the real world one tends not to limit oneself.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!